# Can someone help me solve the below SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using the following 2 tables, give the Daily Sales for each player by name where each transaction that happens before 4am of a day should count toward the sales of the day prior. For example, a sale that happened on Sep 10 at 3am should count toward the sale figure of Sep 9th.

[image: 1]

Comment: You won't learn if you don't try. Subtract 4 hours and then sum by date.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your query that demonstrates your best attempt to resolve this yourself, and then explain 1) what isn't giving you the results you expect and 2) the results you expect

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

Posting images is not helpful. Posting desired results eliminates any assumptions.  That said, here is a little nudge

```
Select A.Player_ID
      ,A.Name
      ,Trans_Date = convert(date,dateadd(HOUR,-4,B.Tran_Time))
      ,Sales      = sum(B.Sales)
 From  Player_Table A
 Join  Trans_Table  B on A.Player_ID=B.Player_ID
 Group By A.Player_ID
         ,A.Name
         ,convert(date,dateadd(HOUR,-4,B.Tran_Time))
```

Another approach would be to aggregate the Trans_Table first and then join the results to the Player_Table.  **Have some fun and experiment.**